# Expected all tensors to be on the same device,when checking argument for argument tensors in method wrapper___cat

Tags: pytorch

I want to align my output tensor with the target tensor, so that their shapes could be the same for MSE-Loss calculation. So if output tensor shorter as target, there will be added zeros to make it have same length. For that purpose I've created `outputAlignment` function, which takes output and target tensors as arguments, and compares their lengths.

So when I'm running this function, I become error, which says:

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument tensors in method wrapper___cat)
```

```py
def outputAlignment(outputTensor,targetTensor):
  diffNumber = (targetTensor.shape)[1] - (outputTensor.shape)[1]
  if diffNumber > 0: 
    zeroTensor = torch.zeros(diffNumber)
    zeroTensor = zeroTensor.to(device)
    alignedTensor = [] 
    print(f"zero tensor device: {zeroTensor.get_device()}") # zero tensor device: 0
    print(f"output tensor: {outputTensor.get_device()}") # output tensor: 0
    print(f"target tensor: {targetTensor.get_device()}") # target tensor: 0
    for tensor in outputTensor:
      print("tensor device: ",tensor.get_device()) # tensor device:  0
      alignedTensor += [torch.cat((tensor,zeros),0)] # Here is the RuntimeError
    return alignedTensor
  elif diffNumber < 0:
    shortenedTensor = outputTensor[:,:(outputTensor.shape)[1]]
    return shortenedTensor
  else:  
    return outputTensor
```

As you may see I expicitly change device on new created `zeroTensor` and all the outputs show, that tensors are on `cuda` device (so zero).

I would be helpful, if someone could point my error out.

Comment: Where is `zeros` coming from? Do you mean `zeroTensor`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @aaossa, which pointed in the comment section, where my error was. It was little type error with `zeros`. Also I've added `pad_sequence` from pytorch as a return value, because otherwise I am returning only list of tensors and not the tensor as it. It doesn't affect anyhow functionality of the code. The code looks now like this:

```py
def outputAlignment(outputTensor,targetTensor):

  diffNumber = (targetTensor.shape)[1] - (outputTensor.shape)[1]
  
  if diffNumber > 0: 
    zeroTensor = torch.zeros(diffNumber)
    zeroTensor = zeroTensor.to(device)
    alignedTensor = [] 

    for tensor in outputTensor:
      alignedTensor += [torch.cat((tensor,zeroTensor),0)] 
    return torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(alignedTensor,batch_first=True, padding_value=0)

  elif diffNumber < 0:
    shortenedTensor = outputTensor[:,:(outputTensor.shape)[1]]
    return torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence([shortenedTensor],batch_first=True, padding_value=0)

  else:  
    return outputTensor
```